# Python regex compile and search strings with numbers and words

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have three strings which have information of the street name and apartment number.

`"32 Syndicate street"`, `"Street 45 No 100"` and `"15, Tom and Jerry Street"`

Here,

```
"32 Syndicate street" -> {"street name": "Syndicate street", "apartment number": "32"}
"Street 45 No 100" -> {"street name": "Street 45", "apartment number": "No 100"}
"15, Tom and Jerry Street" -> {"street name": "Tom and Jerry Street", "apartment number": "15"}
```

I am trying to use Python's regex to get the street names and apartment numbers separately.
This is my current code, which is having problems:

```
import re 
for i in ["32 Syndicate street","Street 45 No 100","15, Tom and Jerry Street"]:
    ###--- write patterns for street names
    pattern_street = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+\s?\w+ | [A-Za-z]+\s?[A-Za-z]+\s?[A-Za-z]+\s? | [A-Za-z]+\s?)') 
    match_street = pattern_street.search(i) 
    
    ###--- write patterns for apartment numbers
    pattern_aptnum = re.compile(r'(^\d+\s? | [A-Za-z]+[\s?]+[0-9]+$)') 
    match_aptnum = pattern_aptnum.search(i)

    fin_street = match_street[0] ##--> final street name
    fin_aptnum = match_aptnum[0] ##--> final apartment name 

    print("street--",fin_street)
    print("apartmentnumber--",fin_aptnum)
```

I get the following output:

```
street--  Syndicate street 
apartmentnumber-- 32 
street-- Street 45 
apartmentnumber--  No 100
```

I have two problems:

1. I am not able to get the apartment number "15" for the final string.
2. Why is there a space in the beginning of `street--  Syndicate street` and `apartmentnumber--  No 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get the apartment number using

```
^\d+|\bNo\s*\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eCrj9V/1). The `^\d+|\bNo\s*\d+` regex matches either one or more digits at the start of string, or `No`, zero or more whitespaces and then one or more digits.

To capture the street information, you can use

```
^\d+,?\s*(.*)|^(.*?)\s+No\s*\d+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eCrj9V/2). Details:

- `^\d+,?\s*(.*)` - start of string, one or more digits, an optional comma, 0+ whitespaces and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible captured into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `^(.*?)\s+No\s*\d+` - start of string, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible captured into Group 2, 1+ whitespaces, `No`, 0+ whitespaces, and then 1+ digits.

In Python, never compile regexps inside a `for` loop, do it before. See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zA3Sgr):

```
import re 

pattern_aptnum = re.compile(r'^\d+|\bNo\s*\d+')
pattern_street = re.compile(r'^\d+,?\s*(.*)|^(.*?)\s+No\s*\d+') 
for i in ["32 Syndicate street","Street 45 No 100","15, Tom and Jerry Street"]:
    fin_street = ""
    fin_aptnum = ""
    print("String:", i)
    match_street = pattern_street.search(i)
    if match_street:
        fin_street = match_street.group(1) or match_street.group(2)
    match_aptnum = pattern_aptnum.search(i)
    if match_aptnum:
        fin_aptnum = match_aptnum.group()

    print("street--",fin_street)
    print("apartmentnumber--",fin_aptnum)
```

Output:

```
String: 32 Syndicate street
street-- Syndicate street
apartmentnumber-- 32
String: Street 45 No 100
street-- Street 45
apartmentnumber-- No 100
String: 15, Tom and Jerry Street
street-- Tom and Jerry Street
apartmentnumber-- 15
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to not call the `compile` inside the `for` loop? I am actually trying to use different `compile` statements based on the number of "variables" my string has.

Comment: @Srivatsan You lose performance that way. You do not need `re.compile` if you need to build patterns from variables inside a loop, just use `re.search` directly then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `re.compile(... , re.X)` if you want to use freely white space in the regex.
2. `print()` inserts a space by default between its several arguments.